# Threading.Times doesn't work

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I have a problem with Timer in Threading

From [documentation:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects)

> ```
>  def hello():
>     print "hello, world"
>     t = Timer(30.0, hello)   
>     t.start() # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
> ```
>
> cancel()
>
> Stop the timer, and cancel the execution of the timer’s action. This will only work if the timer is still in its waiting stage.

Here is my code:

```
def function_terminate():
        raise Exception

def do():
    thr = threading.Timer(5.0, function_terminate(), args=())
    thr.start()
    sleep(2)
    thr.cancel()
```

This code throws **Exception**

But according to the documentation, *function_terminate()* method must be run after 5 sec after calling.
Since, I have *thr.cancel* after 2 seconds (*sleep(2)*), thread must be cancel and **Exception** will never throw

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the function as an argument, you are calling it.

This

```
thr = threading.Timer(5.0, function_terminate(), args=())
```

has to become this

```
thr = threading.Timer(5.0, function_terminate, args=())
```

In your case, you were passing return value of function_terminate (None), not the function alone.

Comment: For reference for future viewers, to assign functions or pass as arguments you omit the ()s from a function. (e.g. `x = hello` to assign `hello()` to `x`. You would call the function by adding the ()s `x()`)